# PHPExcel could not open file

Tags: php, smarty, phpexcel

I am trying to read data from excel file using PHPExcelReader library. I have written smarty function and when I call this function I get this error.

> The filename filename.xls is not readable

I have spent hours in trying solving it but could not find any solution. Please Help!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the webserver have read access to the file?

Comment: it is reading all other files I tried txt file, it is opening.

Answer (score 3):

1. check the path to the file you want to write, you can even try it with: `file_exists ("/path/to/file.xls ");`
2. if the file exists and is a local file on your computer, check to see if you have not opened with Excel or another program
3. I recommend you work with local files such as `/user/public/docs/filex.xls` instead remote files

Comment: I am trying to upload it on web host i-e one.com

Comment: can add to your question specifies the path where you try to open the file, if possible, the code snippet

Comment: [link] i am using it like this <br>
$data->read('http://example.com/folder1/'.$filename);<br>and it give me error that file could not be read but i have tried reading other formats they are fine only xls is not read

Comment: please tell me which formats

because there cuertos formats that can not be read directly, for example depending on server configuration, it can try to open the XLS file download directamenteo and I think this is what is happening to you.

I will try better reocmiendo to local routes or try to look at the configuration of your server (IIS, Apache, etc.) to see how it is serving the content based on mime type